# Can't run Remarkable, a markdown editor, on Debian GNOME

Tags: debian, gnome

I have Debian with GNOME *(oct-2014)*. I have downloaded [Remarkable](http://remarkableapp.github.io/) as a [deb package](https://remarkableapp.github.io/linux/download.html). The installation with GDebi has ran correctly. However when I execute the application in the console, I have the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/remarkable", line 65, in <module>
  import remarkable
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/remarkable/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

I've checked dependency and there was no problem. It seems there is a problem with Python but I know almost nothing about Python. How can I install/activate this module named `gi.repository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system (Debian based) this `import` is provided by the package `python3-gi`. In older versions running with python version 2.7, this was provided by `python-gi`. You can install that with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gi
```

In principle it is possible to have such packages work with both python 2.7 and python 3.x. I have not investigated why this was not done (or possible). But the most likely problem is that the dependency of your `Remarkable` package was never updated, and that it e.g. still pulls in `python-gi`. To check that you can do:

```
dpkg -l | grep -F python | grep -F -- -gi
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! However, I still get warning messages but it seems related to gtk.

Comment: @Spiralwise The warnings might not be from Python, but indeed from underlying libraries. If they bother you just post another Question on this site with "How do I get rid of warning..." or "Can I just ignore warning ..."